# Amazon Zocalo with Active Directory - can't login

Tags: active-directory, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012-r2

I just setup a Zocalo site for my company using the active directory connect option. The Domain Controller we are connecting to is in an AWS VPC. I setup the zocalo site fine and it says active, but when I try to login to the web console it just sends me right back to the login page. I know the credentials are correct, and if I enter a wrong password just to test, it gives me the invalid password/username warning, so I know I have the credentials right. The AD user has been granted all privileges I can think of - access to users, able to add devices to domain, etc. Anyone know what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the AWS Console, select the radio button in front of your site URL, and from the Actions menu, pick "Set an Administrator."  Enter an existing account, and it'll grant some additional rights to the account you specify...

After setting the administrator, you should be able to click the Site & log in with that user's credentials.  You'll have an Administration link on the left side of the page, where you can enable additional users for Zocalo...Accounts won't be able to log in to the Zocalo site until they've been invited/activated for Zocalo.

Optionally, you can change the security so that current users can invite new users by sharing files or folders with them...this is on the administration tab, under Security, click the Change button to the right of "Only administrators can invite new users."

Comment: Wow, I completely overlooked the "Set An Administrator" Option. THANK YOU!

Comment: One other slightly related question. Now that I'm into the administrator panel, I tried to change my password or timezone and it says it cannot update my profile. Is this an active directory permission issue, and how do I enable that?

Comment: hmm...I haven't run into that before...I'd expect timezone to be stored with the app, not part of your AD account...and I'd think it would use individual user's permissions for the password change...

On the password side, it might be that your new password doesn't  meet the complexity requirements or reset lifecycle set by your domain policy...That doesn't explain the timezone though.

Comment: Did you see yesterday's announcement for the AWS Directory Service? http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-directory-service